# HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException file not found

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Im facing an exception `HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/common/IncludeGoogleKey.jsp&quot; not found`

Looking that system can not find file "/common/IncludeGoogleKey.jsp" where using statement `<jsp:include page="/common/IncludeGoogleKey.jsp" />` to include the file, file is on the same location as mentioned and when i click on the page attribute by pressing the Ctrl key(as using eclipse) IDE takes me to that file it means that file exist on correct location but when i refresh the web page it gives exception.

**EDIT**
`webapps/AppName/common/IncludeGoogleKey.jsp` is the file need to be includ, where

`webapps/AppName/PVS/P_Search.jsp` is the file having the include statement.

full trace is

```
May 09, 2014 1:28:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [/appName] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/common/IncludeGoogleKey.jsp&quot; not found] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/common/IncludeGoogleKey.jsp&quot; not found
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:412)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:392)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jsp.PVS.Partner_005fSearch_jsp._jspService(Partner_005fSearch_jsp.java:290)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.mind.common.CharsetEncoding.doFilter(CharsetEncoding.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat60AgentValve.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please see the edited part now, @AlexandreFILLATRE

Comment: attach the screen shot of your folder structure.

Comment: @DeepakTiwari Plz see the screenshot, this is a maven based project with status framework.

Comment: You sure you didn't take the usage directions a little bit too literally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment "**/common/IncludeGoogleKey.jsp**" should be present in :

*/<**WEB_Project_Name**>/WebContent/
 common/IncludeGoogleKey.jsp*

Make sure `IncludeGoogleKey.jsp` is present in above location.

Comment: thnx for the help, actually the file was there but server was not getting it, dont know why, but when i rebuild the system and deployed on server it worked fine, :)

Comment: @NoNaMe I faced same issue suddenly on working application and when restarted the server it worked fine again. This should not be an accepted answer as this doesn't solve the questioned problem. It makes wrong impression on visitor having similar problem as your.

Answer (score 0):

Have the similar problem - code just stopped working on Servlet-to-JSP forwarding.

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError

How to fix it:

- Quit IDE (I used IDEA)
- Reopen IDE
- If you have something in red - push "Reimport ALL Maven Projects" (As I used Maven)

Answer (score 0):

The common folder must be moved to WEB-INF directory. The statement is edited as follows (I use IntelliJ IDEA):

```
 <jsp:include page="WEB-INF/common/IncludeGoogleKey.jsp" />
```